# Is there a way to only ouput the long list of a directory itself not its contents

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

Is there a way to only ouput the long list of a directory itself not its contents.

ls -l directory   outputs the contents as a list

ls -l filename    outputs the file itself

Comment: Have you omitted the file name? `ls -l`

Comment: Did you read the man page of [ls(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) or tried `/bin/ls --help` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ls -d directory_name` should give you what you want.
It can be combined with `-l` or other switches, of course.